# Where is the Windows bash directory in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed the Windows 10 Anniversary Update on my computer.

I would like to know where the `/root` directory in Bash prompt is within Windows?

I would like to be able to write files in Bash that are accessible from Windows too

i.e.- 
If I do:

`touch /root/foo`

Where do I go to access `foo` in My PC

Comment: Did you Google first?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes, and all I could find were articles about where the C drive is located inside the Bash script, but nothing the other way around

Comment: really? I copied your question into Google and [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/759880/253474) appears on top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access linux/Ubuntu files from Windows 10 WSL?](https://superuser.com/questions/1110974/how-to-access-linux-ubuntu-files-from-windows-10-wsl)

Comment: (I am suggesting to close as dupe in reverse-chronological order as the other question is both more general and has far better and more up-to-date answers.)

Answer (score 11):

I believe this link will answer your question:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice

In short:

> %localappdata%\Lxss\rootfs

or

> C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Lxss\rootfs

Comment: `rootfs` is deceiving. There's nothing in the `home` dir inside there, it's actually at `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\lxss\home\`.

Comment: @mpen as the same for me , this is not true path.

Answer (score 1):

The folder changed again:

```
%localappdata%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs
```

---

```
C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, running last windows update (creators fall) with ubuntu upgraded, the files are still in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\lxss\ but the lxss directory became "invisible". However, just editing the path at the top of the windows explorer manually make it work

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the WSL file-system from within Windows [is not supported](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/). As soon as you do anything more than just reading those files from within the Windows environment, things will go wrong.

---

But the following part of the question is not impossible and easily supported, so I'll answer this:

> I would like to be able to write files in Bash that are accessible from Windows too

You can't (should not) access the Linux filesystem from within Windows, but you *can* quite easily access the Windows file-system from within WSL. You will find all your fixed lettered Windows NTFS drives mounted under `/mnt/*`, so your `"C-Drive"` is mounted on `/mnt/c`, and so on.

For example your Windows home user path will be something like `/mnt/c/Users/<usernamehere>`

### Mounting removable drives

You can mount some filesystems yourself: [MSDN Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/)

```bash
sudo mkdir /mnt/sdcard
sudo mount -t drvfs U: /mnt/sdcard
```

Note that the actual filesystem is in this case was exFAT, so you just use `drvfs` as long as Windows can read the actual file system.

### More info

- [Github ticket 1079](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1079)
- [Github ticket 891](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/891)